# rewrite but want to preserve the URL on browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I want my apache webserver to redirect to other wordpress server but want the same URL on he browser

for this I am using

`<virtualhost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example-hello.com/$1 [P]
   </virtualhost>`

it get redirected but still shows the change of URL which I want it to be  Invisible.my web server URL is domain-name.com

Comment: FWIW P flag for rewrite proxies does not redirect, so it should not change the url in browser, if you want to reverse proxy that is, you can also use ProxyPass directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use frames. Not that beauty but fully functional and compliant. Create your **index.html** page with nothing but the following content:

```
<frameset rows="100%">
   <frameset cols="100%">
      <frame src="http://www.yourdomain.com" frameborder="0">
   </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Do not use the common **html**, **head**, **body** (and so on) tags, just what I've showed above.

Then change **www.yourdomain.com** to your desired wordpress url.

Specs.: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/present/frames.html#h-16.2.1

Comment: Thank you for that and so I have add the above to the root directory of the web server if I am not wrong

Comment: Exactly. Create this as your **index.html** on the root and forget about this server space - everything showed will be from your wordpress server.

Comment: Thank you Sai for your consideration. Best.